# Table numbering mismatch in 4 tables , where one of them is longtable

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, tabularx, labels

4 tables are here. The caption and label of table 1,3 and 4 are outputted as table 1, 2 and 3. But table 2 is a longtable and its table label is not showing. How to output their table label and captions sequentially?

```
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{first table}
\label{tab:1}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} |l|c|}
\toprule
     some codes
\midrule
  some codes
\end{tabular*}
\smallskip
\scriptsize
\end{table}
\\
```

```
\begin{longtable}
%\setlength 
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} |l|c|r|}
\caption{second table}\label{tab:2}\\
\toprule
some codes
   \midrule
    some codes
    \bottomrule
    
 \hline   
\end{tabular*}

\smallskip
\scriptsize
\end{longtable}
\\
```

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\caption{Third table}
\label{tab:3}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|r|} \hline
some codes
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\smallskip
\scriptsize
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\caption{Summary of overall query result}
\label{tab:4}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|r|} \hline
some codes

\end{tabular}
\smallskip
\scriptsize
\end{center}
\end{table}\\
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Trying to create a small example document that includes the `longtable` code you show, results in a bunch of error messages when trying to compile it. Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error. Instead, try to fix the error messages first....

Comment: ...  If you don't understand them/the reason for them, please ask a question specifically about the error messages. Please also include a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that others can use in order to get the same output/error messages as you do.  Once your document compiles without errors, you can take a look at the output and see if it suits your needs.

Comment: Regarding the issue itself: Zarko already pointed out the syntax errors in your `lontgable` environment in [their answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/560512/134144). There are however some more things to keep in mind: In your firts table, you combine lines from the `booktabs` package (`\toprule`, `\midrule)  with vertical lines. Please be aware that the horizontal lines from the booktabs package were desigend to be used without vertical lines and are thus incompatible with them. This is the reason for the small white gaps around the intersections, that you can see in your first table. ...

Comment: ... Using the `center` environment (begin{center}, `\end{center}` inside of your `table` environment will add some additional vertical white space. To avoid that, use `\centering` instead. Lastly, you use of `\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}` makes me suspect that you use a `twocolumn` documentclass. Is that correct? Please be warned that `longtable` will not work correctly in a `twocolumn` documentclass and you should get a corresponding warning along the lines of "Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode."

Answer (score 2):

After merging your code fragments, correcting wrong syntax for use of the `longtable` I obtain expected correct result:

[image]

As you can see, the culprit is code for long table. In a `longtable` you cant include `tabular` (or other table  environments as you do. After `\begin{longtable}` should follows column specifications (`c`, `l`, `r` or `p{...}`. See MWE below.

MWE, which produce showed result is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption{first table}
\label{tab:1}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} |l|c|}
\toprule
     some codes &   some codes  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}

\begin{longtable}{|l|c|r|}
\caption{second table}
\label{tab:2}\\
    \toprule
     some codes &   some codes  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable}

    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Third table}
\label{tab:3}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|r|} \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7   \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Summary of overall query result}
\label{tab:4}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|r|} \hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4   \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```